# JQ convert json array to object properties

Tags: json, object, jq

I have a json structured like this:

```
[
    { 
      "name": "object1",
      "prop": "prop1",
      "props": [
        { "prop1": "value1" },
        { "prop2": "value2" },
        { "prop3": "value3" }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "name": "object2",
      "prop": "prop2",
      "props": [
        { "prop1": "value4" },
        { "prop2": "value5" },
        { "prop3": "value6" }
      ]
    }
]
```

I would like to extract the content of the `props` variable and have it as extra object properties, looking like this:

```
[
    { 
      "name": "object1",
      "prop": "prop1",
      "prop1": "value1",
      "prop2": "value2",
      "prop3": "value3"
    },
    { 
      "name": "object2",
      "prop": "prop2",
      "prop1": "value4",
      "prop2": "value5",
      "prop3": "value6"
    },
]
```

I've been trying to use `map` but I can't seem to be able to get rid of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `add` to merge the propN objects into one, `del` to remove the original `props`:

```
jq '[.[] | . + (.props | add) | del(.props)]' file.json
```

You can indeed use `map` to shorten it a bit:

```
jq 'map(. + (.props | add) | del(.props))' file.json
```

Comment: Equivalently `jq 'map(. + (.props | add) | del(.props))'`

Comment: If I wanted to do something else with the rest of the object properties I would need to do it separately, right? `jq '{...} | map(...)' file.json`.

Comment: @FedericoNafria: You can process the result of the map, e.g. `map(. + (.props | add) | del(.props)) | .[].name |= ascii_upcase`.